# Как окрасить body в два цвета?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, веб-дизайн

Сейчас у body лишь один цвет - чёрный, как сделать так чтобы допустим только половина страницы была черного цвета, а вторая серого?

Comment: Можно ли это сделать как-то кроме background-image?

Comment: если только тег img зафиксировать или canvas или svg

Comment: понял, спасибо /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще вариант с псевдоэлементом для `body`:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #777;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2;
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus iure facilis eius, vel porro consequatur. Debitis et rerum distinctio dolore, ipsa, explicabo perferendis ducimus dolores fuga, vel, repellendus officiis non!
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem nesciunt perferendis et magnam tempore tenetur qui nemo porro ipsum. Maxime officiis ipsam quis recusandae repellat reiciendis repudiandae vitae praesentium ut atque id, dolores corrupti
      fugit! Ipsam dolores suscipit, error alias, quasi et mollitia ducimus aperiam. Eligendi, delectus! Doloremque, dicta, laborum!
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus iure facilis eius, vel porro consequatur. Debitis et rerum distinctio dolore, ipsa, explicabo perferendis ducimus dolores fuga, vel, repellendus officiis non!
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem nesciunt perferendis et magnam tempore tenetur qui nemo porro ipsum. Maxime officiis ipsam quis recusandae repellat reiciendis repudiandae vitae praesentium ut atque id, dolores corrupti
      fugit! Ipsam dolores suscipit, error alias, quasi et mollitia ducimus aperiam. Eligendi, delectus! Doloremque, dicta, laborum!
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus iure facilis eius, vel porro consequatur. Debitis et rerum distinctio dolore, ipsa, explicabo perferendis ducimus dolores fuga, vel, repellendus officiis non!
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem nesciunt perferendis et magnam tempore tenetur qui nemo porro ipsum. Maxime officiis ipsam quis recusandae repellat reiciendis repudiandae vitae praesentium ut atque id, dolores corrupti
      fugit! Ipsam dolores suscipit, error alias, quasi et mollitia ducimus aperiam. Eligendi, delectus! Doloremque, dicta, laborum!
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

С помощью градиента. Вот хороший сайт, чтобы самому не мучаться https://cssgradient.io/ .
Например:

```
background: rgb(29,229,253);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(29,229,253,1) 50%, rgba(252,176,69,1) 50%);
```